# Change caret thickness

Tags: front-end

Is it possible to change the caret thickness in the front-end?

[image]

I am finding it hard to find visually. The system thickness has no effect on it.

**Env:**
Windows 10 1909
Mathematica 12.0

Comment: You're talking about the character `^`, which is defined in the font being used?

Comment: @michaelE2 ...no no  the blinking straight line that appears while typing..looks like |

Comment: I think it's called a cursor.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think its also called a caret...especially in the context of input/text entry...from getCaret/setCaretPostion etc....anyways added a pic for clarity

Comment: OK, you may be right. To me a "caret" a proofreading mark indicating something is missing, which is the Latin meaning of *caret*. Since it is used to indicate where something is to be inserted, people have probably been using it. For instance a red caret is shown in the input `Table[a]`. In any case, the vertical line called a "cursor" in the docs and options, though, but a search through the docs, options or Front End resources did not yield anything useful.  Someone here probably knows where it comes from.

Comment: lineage, by “system thickness”, can you please be specific of what you have attempted to change to enact the change in thickness? Did you reopen Mathematica after this?

Comment: @CATrevillian I meant OS Windows system settings....the system wide caret thickness has now been increased from its default but mathematica doesn't track with that...yeah i have restarted mathematica several times since then